# Prove that parallels of sides of a triangle drawn from the centroid, divides each sides in three parts.

Tags: geometry

I have been trying for hours, but I don't know if I should approach it through areas or Euclid's Fifth Postulate.

[image: Every side should be divided into 3 equal parts]

Comment: do you know that centroid cut the median in 2:1 ratio.

Comment: I would use similar triangles since there are a lot of parallel lines here. I would also need the fact the the centroid divides the median into $2:1$, which in turn is derived with area arguments.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This method does not use the centroid $2:1$ property I mentioned in the comments.

Construct the median $AE$.

Using the parallel lines, we have $\triangle AFD \sim \triangle ABE$ and $\triangle AGD \sim \triangle ACE$.

This gives the corresponding sides:

$$\frac {FD}{BE} = \frac {AD}{AE} = \frac {GD}{CE}$$

Since $AE$ is a median, $BE = EC$. Hence $FD = GD$.

By similar triangles or the intercept theorem (due to $AF // HD$), we have $AH = HG$.

Similarly, $HD = DI$, and by $DG // IC$ we have $HG = GC$.

Hence the side $AC$ is trisected, and using similar arguments we see that all sides are trisected.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Consider side a. Centroid is where all three medians of triangle cross. So  median from A  on opposite side  a is also the median from the centroid D, which is the vertex of small triangle DIE its base IE on that side a of triangle, that is we have subtracted a certain measure (IJ=JE)from half of the side a(BJ=JC) which results remain portions JC and BI must be equal.Now draw a line from E  parallel with side c and mark its intersection with side b as K. KD is equal to the base of small triangle IE. it is also equal to segment DH  (because the median of triangle bisect all lines parallel with base a). Also HD=BI. Hence all three segments of  side a , i.e. BI, IE and EC are equal. This is also true for other two sides.